# How cluster event bus in Vertx works?

Tags: vert.x

I am new to Vertx. I am confused about event bus in clustering environment.

As documentation of vertx

> The event bus doesn’t just exist in a single Vert.x instance. By
>   clustering different Vert.x instances together on your network they
>   can form a single, distributed event bus.

How exactly event bus of different Vert.x instances are joined together in cluster to form a single distributed event bus and the role of ClusterManager in this case? How the communication between nodes work in distributed event bus? Please explain me this in detail of technical. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is more info about clustering in the [cluster managers](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_cluster_managers) section of the docs.

The key points are:

- Vert.x has a clustering SPI; implementations are named "cluster managers"
- Cluster managers, provide Vert.x with discovery and membership management of the clustered nodes
- Vert.x does not use the cluster manager for message transport, it uses its own set of TCP connections

If you want to try this out, take a look at [Infinispan Cluster Manager examples](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/infinispan-examples).

For more technical details, I guess the best option is to go to the source code.